# Send credentials surely to an API

Tags: security, api-key

Say I have a server `server` and an API `API`, and I want to send a POST operation to `API` from `server`, I'll need to include some credentials to allow the POST-request (note, `API` only accepts https-repsonses). Here, `API` is a Google Compute Engine and `server` a Google App Engine - if that makes any difference.

My first thought would to use some generic key and a SHA256 e.g `key = SHA(today_date+salt_key)` and send `key` to the `API` along with the request. On the server I would then calculate `check_key = SHA(today_date+salt_key)` and see if `key==check_key` but IMO that won't solve anything, since the credentials now is just the hashed-credentials i.e if someone got the hashed credentials (`key`), they can just send them directly along with a malicious POST-request.

So, how do I overcome this issue? Do I encrypt the API-key on `server` and decrypt it on `API` (and is there any "best practice" encryption-schemes for that? Or is there an easiere method ?

Answer (score 0):

What we usually do in API design to authenticate the user is usually one of the following:

1. pass the credentials from the user in plain text, authenticate the user on the server, give him back a session cookie or some token (e.g. JWT) in return,
2. pass some API token and authenticate every single request based on this,
3. use HTTP basic authentication and pass the credentials (or the digest of the credentials) in every request.

There are other authentication mechanisms (like zero knowledge, proof of knowledge authentication schemes), but they are not as popular as the ones above.

What does prevent you from using point 1 on the list above? Are you trying to reinvent the point 3 using digest of the credentials?

Comment: My concern is to avoid the API key being captured by e.g man-in-the middle. If I send the request with the API-key as payload, then anyone who captures that request now have POST rights, thus I'm trying to make it "man-in-the-middle" secure.

Comment: I just thought about - couldn't a salt-key be applied by the server and API in the same way, such that the API key is then e.g {"key":abce, "salted":h8fyao10} thus the API can then salt "abce" in a specific way, and see if it gets the "salted" key?

Comment: i.e like `salted_key = salt_func("abce")`, `key = sha256(salted_key)` and then send `{"org_string":"abce", "encrypted":key}` to API which then evaluates  `sha256(salt_func(org_string)) == encrypted`  (a bit like public/private key-sharing)